# how to reorder an NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableDictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2, nsmutabledictionary

In a loop with json data I'm creating an NSMutableDictionary and inside it I'm storing json parsed values :

```
for j in json {
            var jsonValues = NSMutableDictionary()

//Create main value
            guard let value = j.valueForKey("value")?.valueForKey("value")! else{
                continue
            }

            //Get name
            guard let Name : String = (value.valueForKey("Name")?.valueForKey("en") as? String) else {
                continue
            }

            jsonValues["name"] = Name

            //Get geoposition
            guard let geoposition = value.valueForKey("geoposition") else {
                return
            }

            //Get lat
            if let lat = geoposition.valueForKey("lat") as? String {

                jsonValues["lat"] = lat
                let flat : Float = (lat as AnyObject).floatValue


                //Get lng
                if let lng = geoposition.valueForKey("lng") as? String{

                    jsonValues["lng"] = lng
                    let flng : Float = (lng as AnyObject).floatValue

                    let metters : CLLocationDistance = getDistance(flat, flng: flng)

                    jsonValues["distance"] = floor(metters)
                }
            }else{}


nsDict.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(["\(c)" : jsonValues])
c += 1
}
```

at the end of the loop I put the jsonValues mutableDictionary inside a global var, another NSMutableDictionary, named nsDict.

I would like to reorder my dictionary of dictionaries, using the `["distance"]` value, which is in metters, so I can show it in a tableView from lower distance to upper. I've  been stackoverflowing and googling for a while, but I find only examples with `dictionary.sort()` which is useless for me since I use an NSMutableDictionary. Couldn't find any example with NsMutableDictionary and doesn't really understand the apple docs. In another language, like php, I would had do this with two `do{}while` But I can't manage to do it in swift 2 with the given methods . Anybody can help me?

This is an NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableDictionaries this is why I think the parsing technique is not same as to order one NSMutableDictionary

Comment: May I ask why you're using `NSMutableDictionary` in the first place?

Comment: @AMomchilov if you know a better approach of what I'm doing you are welcome to post it

Comment: I don't know what you're doing or trying to achieve. 1) From what I see here, you're not using any legacy frameworks that would require you to use `Foundation`'s collections (`NSArray`,`NSDictionary`, etc.). 2) This seems like a better fit for structs, which could conform to the `Comparable` interface. That would make comparison a piece of cake.

Comment: My suggestion: restart from scratch, using Swift types (Dictionary, Array, struct) and Swift methods to sort them, instead of Foundation's ones. You will *feel* better, which is always good, and your code will have less ambiguities.

Comment: ok I think it's the better approach too so let's start from scratch :(

Comment: This seems like a case for structs. If you have many dictionaries with the same keys, it's a fair indication you should be using structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutatbleDictionary` doesn't retain order (sorted or insertion). You can't sort it.

You need a different approach, such as using an `NSArray` of sorted keys. See [NSDictionary - Sorting Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-SW23).